# Genymotion not able to find SDK location

Tags: android, genymotion

I install android-sdk through `brew cask install android-sdk`. its been downloaded in `/usr/local/share/android-sdk` location. However, when I am trying to set this path to Genymotion's ADB setting. it says android sdk not found.

[image]

folder inside android-sdk

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion looks for two binaries provided by the Android SDK: `adb` and `aapt`.

It looks for `adb` in:

- `$sdkPath/platform-tools`
- `$sdkPath/tools`
- `$sdkPath`

And for `aapt` in:

- `$sdkPath/build-tools/*/`
- `$sdkPath/platform-tools`
- `$sdkPath/platforms/*/tools`
- `$sdkPath/tools`
- `$sdkPath`

You should check if those are installed in `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`.